# Send e-mail while Looping though dictionary

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com

I'm trying to send multiple e-mails with different file attachments in each one.

Like this: 
file_A go to mail_a@mail.com
file_B go to mail_b@mail.com
...

I tried this code, but when I'm looping though the dictionary all of my e-mails goes to mail_c@mail.com, instead of A to A, B to B, C to C as intended.

```py
import pandas as pd
import shutil, os
import os
import tempfile
import win32com.client as win32 
import glob, os

npath="yourpath/"

files=['file_a.xlsx','file_b.xlsx','file_c.xlsx']

mails=dict(zip(['mail_a@mail.com','mail_b@mail.com','mail_c@mail.com'],files))

for file in os.listdir(npath):
    if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
        outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
        mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
        for id,i in mails.items():
            mail.To = id            
        mail.Subject = 'Test'
        mail.HtmlBody = 'testing'
        mail.Attachments.Add(os.path.join(npath,file))
        mail.Display()
```

I'm pretty sure my problem is this loop or my dictionary, but after trying for hours couldn't solve by my self.

```
for id,i in mails.items():
            print(id)
            mail.To = id
```

Comment: Your loop returns correct order of id. The dictionary also contains correct key value pair. Your `for loop` ends at mail_c and hence getting selected for all files.

Comment: Yes, so how to solve it?

Comment: Side comment: why open a new Outlook instance for each loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should use `mails` dict to iterate over the list of files, here is an example:

```
files=['file_a.xlsx','file_b.xlsx','file_c.xlsx']

mails=dict(zip(['mail_a@mail.com','mail_b@mail.com','mail_c@mail.com'],files))

for mail_id, file in mails.items():
    if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
        outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
        mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
        mail.To = mail_id            
        mail.Subject = 'Test'
        mail.HtmlBody = 'testing'
        mail.Attachments.Add(os.path.join(npath,file))
        mail.Display()
```

If you need to use exatcly your method, you have to add a file match check in the second loop:

```
    for mail_id, file_name in mails.items():
        if file.endswith(file_name):
            mail.To = id  
            break
```

Note: i didn't use `id` as variable name because it's a reserved builtin python function

Comment: Perfect explanation my friend, no need to use my method, yours is better.thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your loop returns correct order of id. The dictionary also contains correct key value pair. Your for loop ends at mail_c and hence getting selected for all files.

You can fix it by bringing the mailing content/logic inside `for loop`

```
for file in os.listdir(npath):
    if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
        outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
        mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
        for id,i in mails.items():
            mail.To = id            
            mail.Subject = 'Test'
            mail.HtmlBody = 'testing'
            mail.Attachments.Add(os.path.join(npath,file))
            mail.Display()
```